# Check unique data for multiple rows in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I have, lets say user name unique and I need to insert many users at one query (It could be thousands of users). What would be the best approach to check for each user if the username already exists? Using PostgreSql.

Comment: The only way to do the "insert" with one query is to use a staging table -- and then join to see what the new users are in the single insert query.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you tell me more specifically? And what about performance?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `on conflict` clause, e.g.

```
create table my_table(id serial primary key, user_name text unique);
insert into my_table (user_name) values
('John'), ('Ben'), ('Alice'), ('John'), ('Ben'), ('Alice'), ('Sam')
on conflict do nothing;

select *
from my_table;

 id | user_name 
----+-----------
  1 | John
  2 | Ben
  3 | Alice
  7 | Sam
(4 rows)
```

Note the last row, the primary key sequence has been updated three times with no apparent effect.

[Check the syntax of `on conflict`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html).

Comment: Hi! thank you for the answer. What if I need to notify admin that there was duplicate row?

Comment: If you want to manually control the insertion you should not use `on conflict`, as it has been added for automatically skipping (or updating) rows with duplicates. There is no means to notify about conflicts in this construction.

Answer (score 1):

set your username as a `PRIMARY KEY` then the engine will do the check for you with no extra hassle

```
alter table table_name add primary key (username);
```

In case you already have PK, one can just add a constrain

```
alter table table_name add constraint constraint_name UNIQUE (username);
```

Comment: I already have it. But is it right way to handle it in case there is duplication and insertion fails?

Comment: @SomethingElse yes, it is

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me if you want to see those rows that have not been inserted or only those that have. But both requirements can be done using [writeable CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

Assuming the following table:

```
create table some_table (id serial primary key, user_name text unique);
```

To see (only) those rows that have been inserted:

```
insert into some_table (user_name) 
values
  ('Tom'), ('Dick'), ('Harry'), ('Arthur'), ('Mary'), ('Ford'), ('Tom'), ('Zaphod')
on conflict do nothing
returning user_name;
```

To see those rows that have **not** been inserted:

```
with new_data (name) as (
  values
    ('Tom'), ('Dick'), ('Harry'), ('Arthur'), ('Mary'), ('Ford'), ('Tom'), ('Zaphod')
), inserted as (
  insert into some_table (user_name) 
  select name 
  from new_data
  on conflict do nothing
  returning user_name
)
select *
from new_data
where name not in (select user_name from inserted);
```